# Advent of Code 2021: day 10- Syntax Scoring

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, parsing

The following code solves [day 10 in the advent of code challenge](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/10#part2).

The goal for this time around is evaluating whether a line of brackets
is complete, has a syntax error or is missing some closing brackets.

**Examples** of *valid* pair of brackets

```
()
[] 
([])
{()()()}
<([{}])>
[<>({}){}[([])<>]]
(((((((((())))))))))
```

**Example** of incorrect or *corrupted* lines

```
{([(<{}[<>[]}>{[]{[(<()> - Expected ], but found } instead.
[[<[([]))<([[{}[[()]]] - Expected ], but found ) instead.
[{[{({}]{}}([{[{{{}}([] - Expected ), but found ] instead.
[<(<(<(<{}))><([]([]() - Expected >, but found ) instead.
<{([([[(<>()){}]>(<<{{ - Expected ], but found > instead.
```

**Examples** of *incomplete* lines

```
[({(<(())[]>[[{[]{<()<>> - Complete by adding }}]])})].
[(()[<>])]({[<{<<[]>>( - Complete by adding )}>]}).
(((({<>}<{<{<>}{[]{[]{} - Complete by adding }}>}>)))).
{<[[]]>}<{[{[{[]{()[[[] - Complete by adding ]]}}]}]}>.
<{([{{}}[<[[[<>{}]]]>[]] - Complete by adding ])}>.
```

### Problem:

Advent of code 10 was divided into two problems

1. Find the sum of all lines that has a syntax error (`corruped`), where every bracket that causes a syntax error is given a particular value
2. Here we had to find each line that was `incomplete`, complete the line, find the autocomplete score of the completed portion. For every line in the testdata we were then asked to find the median of the autocomplete scores.

### Code

**AOC_10_brackets.txt** The testdata can be found [here](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/10/input), but if the link is dead the data has been included below

```
{[[<{(<{[{{[{[[]{}]{<>{}}}({<>()}{{}{}})]}{({[<>{}]({}[])})[{[{}[]](()<>)}<[{}{}]{()<>}>]}}]<(({{{(){}}{[][]
<<<({((<{<([([<>{}]<{}<>>]{<{}<>>({}<>)}])>}{({(([()[]]{[]()})({{}<>}<(){}>))[(<<><>>[()[]]){{()[]}<
<<<[(({{(([[[[<><>][<><>]]]([[{}{}](<><>)][(<>[]){[]()}])])([[(<{}<>>(()[]))(<[][]>)]]{{<[[]{}]{<
({({([{{[[[{(<(){}><[]{}>)}]]][(<<([()[]](()[]))>[[[{}[]]{[]<>}](<()>[()<>]]]>(<(({}<>){<>[]}){<[]()>}>{[{(
[([{(<[<<[({<[()<>][{}]>({{}{}})}({[<>{}][()()]}[([][]){()[]}]))]>>]>)<<[((([[{{()()}(<>{})}[(<>(
{[[{<[[[[([[{[()[]]<[]()>}<({}())<[]<>>>]({<{}[]>}<<{}<>>>)](([(<>{}){[][]}]<[(){}]({}{})>)[((()){[]})<{{}
{{<<((({(<[({<<>[]><{}{}>}((<>[])([]())))[((()[]){[]{}})]]{<([{}[]]<<>[]>)(({}[]}{[][]})><<([][])([][])>>}
([[(<({[[{[{<[<><>]({}())>}](<[[{}[]](<><>)]{{()<>}[{}]}>{((<><>]<()()>)([(){}]<()>)})}{[<{({}())<<><>>}[(()
(<((([[<<[<[{[()[]][[]{}]}{([]<>){[]{}}}]>]>>{{([[({<>()}(<>{}))]<{(()<>)([])}([<>{}}{{}()})>
(<({{<(<{[{<{[(){}][<>{}]}{[[][]]{<>{}}}>}<(([[][]][<>()])[[{}{}][{}()]])>]}>{{{([<(()())>
(<[{<<(<<<((<[<>[]]>)({[[]<>]}<({}<>)([][])>))[{<[[]()](<>())>{<[]<>><{}()>}}(<<{}<>>(<>[]
<[[(((([[(<[{((){})<{}<>>}{({}<>><{}<>>}]([{<>()}([]<>)]<{()()}({}[])>)>)]{{({([{}<>])(<<>()
<({<(<{[{<<[[[{}[]][()[]]](<()()><()>)]>>[(((([]<>){(){}})<{{}()}({}())>)[<[[]()]{<>[]}><[()[]][<>()]>])[(<<<
([[[{(<<<([[[<<>[]>]]{<([]<>){[]{}}><<[]>({}<>)>}]<(<<{}<>>([])><{<>[]}<{}<>>>)([{[]()}<<>
<({<<(<{(<<(({[]<>}{{}{}})(<<>[]><<>[]>))(<<<><>><[]{}>>{[()[]][()[]]})>>){{<{([{}()]{<>()}){<[][]>({}<>)}}
(([{{(<[([([([[]()]({}))<<[][]><{}()>>][[[{}<>][<>{}]]]){[{[[][]]<{}{}>}<<()<>>(<>())>]}])<{{[(({})<[]()>){[<
{(<<[<{<<{(([[()<>]{<>[]}]{[{}{}]{<>()}})<([[][]]{[]<>}){(()<>)<[]<>>}>)[[{{[]}}]]}<{{((<>)<{}>){
<{<{<{{[<{{<<<<>[]>{()[]}>><[<<>()>{{}[]}]<[{}]{[]()}>>}}>[[{(((<>{}]({}()))<<{}()>[[]()]>)}]{{({[<>()
<[[<<([{([{{[[()()]<{}<>>][{{}()}<()()>]}({([]<>)<<>[]>}{[[][]][()[]]})}[((<{}{}><()[]>){<<>()>((){}
<<{([[{[<{[<([()()]{()<>}>[<[]<>>[[]<>]]>{{[{}{}][()<>]}<[[]{}][{}{}]>}]<((({}<>)<<><>>){{<><>}[()<>]})>
[[[[[{({((([<[<>{}]<{}()>>[<{}[]>[[]{}]]]{{{()<>}<{}[]>>([()()]{{}()})})))}[{{[({<{}[]>}<[[]()]>)(
{[[<[([{((<[<[{}[]][<><>]>({{}{}}[{}{}])]{{({}{}){{}[]}><[{}[]]([]())>}>[{<{()<>}([]())>}]))(<[([[()][[][]]
[(({[((<{<{<<[[]<>]<{}[]>>>{[<[]{}>[[]{}]]{((){})<[]>}}}<<<{{}{}}<<>()>>{<<>[]>([]{})}>>>}{[{{{<[]()>(()<>)}<
{[[[{<([{[<{([<>()]{<>[])){<<><>>([]<>)}}<{[(){}]<()<>>}>>([[<()<>>((){})]][<<[]{}><()()>>(<[
[{(<{[({[{[{{(<>{})({}{})}<(<>[])>}([<()<>>[()<>]]{(()<>)<{}()>})]{([{{}{}}(()<>)][{()()>])[<<[][]>(<>[])>
[[{[{([<<<<([{[][]}{<>()}]([[]<>]<<>[]>))<{[<>()][<>{}]}[((){})]>><[[<{}<>>([]())]]>><<{{(()
<{[<<[[[<{{[<<[]{}>[()<>]><{()()}<()[]>>][[[<>{}][[]()]][<<>>{{}[]}]]}{<<<[]()>({}<>)>>(<[[]()]{<>[]}
{(([({{<(<<[(({}{})[()[]])<<{}{}>(()[])>](([()[]]<{}()>){{<><>}<[][]>})>((<{()()}[{}()]>[{<>()}
<(({(([[<[{[{<{}>(())}{<{}[]>[<>[]]}]{<{()}><<()()>[{}{}]>}}]({<<<()[]>{()<>}>>}[[{(<>){[]}}((())
{{<{<<(([[[{{[{}{}]{<>[]}}}{[<{}<>>[{}<>]]{{[][]}{[]]}}]({<([][])[<>]>{(()())<<><>>}}([([][]){{}()}]<{()[]}{[
[<<<<<[{<{{({[[]()](<>())}{{[]{}}([][])})}(<<[{}{}]({}<>)>[<<>>{()}]>)>({[(<[][]>{{}[]})][[(()())<(){}>]{<()<
{({<<([[(<(([(()[])]{{{}<>)((){})}))[([<(){}>[<>()]]{{<><>}})<({<>{}}(<>[]))>]>({[{([]()){(){
<{[<(<{[(<<{(({}[])(<>()))}[{<[]<>><()[]>}<<{}{}>(<>{})>]>{{{<{}<>>[{}()]}}[<<()()}>(([]{})([]
{<[(([{{{[(<<[{}()]>{(<>())[[]{}]}>){{[{{}[]}{()<>}]{(()<>)<<><>>}}}]}{(<[([[]][{}[]])]>)[[((<{}[]})[
([[[({({{[<<[<[]<>><()>]>{([<><>])(<<><>><<>()>)}>[(([[][]]{()<>}>)([{(){}}({}<>)])]][(<<{{}{}}{()
{([({[{{{[(<<<<><>>([][])>[<[]<>>[()<>]]>)[[(<()[]>)(<<>()>[()<>])]({<[][]>{[][]}}[<()()>[<>[]]])]](<<{<<><>
<((({{<[[({[(([]<>)[[]<>])]{{<{}>{[]<>}}(([][])[()[]])}}{[{<()<>>[()[]]}{{[]<>}{[]()}}]}){([{{{}{}}[(
{<<[[{[<(([[{([][])[<>()]}<{<><>}>](<<[][]>[[]{}]>[{<>}{{}<>}])]{<([()<>]<()[]>)(<[][]>(<>[]))>[{[[]<
([{((<[<<([[[{<>()}(<>())]([(){}](<>[]))][[<[]>]]]<{<[{}[]][[][]]>}([<[]()><<>{}>]<{(){}}[{}{}]>)>)>({([
([{(<<[<{<[[(<[][]>{<><>}){<<>()>}]{({()[]}<<>()>)}][{({(){}}[()()])<[<><>]<<>[]>>}]>}<<[({<
{<({[({{<[[({{(){}}<<>[]>}<({}[]){()())>)<{([]{})([]())}>]]>(<{[((<>[]){[]()})<<()<>>({}<>)>]{{{()[]}}}
{({[[<(<{[[{<<[]()>[()()]>([<>{}]{<>[]))}<{([]())(()<>)}<<[]><[][]>>>][({<{}><[]()>})[<[()[]][()()]>{<{}<>>
{({(((<{<[<(<({}<>)[()()]>{<[]{}><()<>>})[<({}<>)><(<>)<()()>>]>(<(([][])<()<>>)<<<><>>([])>>{(<[]{}>
[{{[([<<(<[<({<><>}{[]()})[{<><>}]>{<(()[])><[<><>]>}][<{[{}<>][[]<>]}(([]{}))>[[([])<{}[]>]{<(){}>({}())}]]
{[<<((<<[([[([()[]]({}()))(<{}()>{(){}})][((<>[]]{{}{}})((()<>)<<><>>)]]{[<(<>[])<[]>>([<>()]{[]
((({({{<[(((<[<>[]]([]<>)>[<[]{}>{<><>}])<{[<>()][()<>]}{<{}<>>[[]()]}>))<[<{(<><>)<()<>>}>[<[[]<>]<[]{
{<<<{<({([({((<><>)[[][]]){[()<>]{<><>}}}<[{[]<>}[<>[]]][[()<>]{(){}}]>)<[[[[]<>]]((<><>))}(<<()<>><<><>>><[[
(({{[({<{<{[[<<>[]>([][])]{<<>()>{{}()>}]{[<<>[]>[{}{}]][{()()}{[]<>}]}}([({{}[]}{{}()}){(()<>){()<>}}
(<([({{{{<[<{{<>[]}{{}}}<[{}{}]<{}{}>>><{{(){}}([]{})}>](<[([]())[()]]>[(<[]<>>[[]{}])])>[{(<[[][]]<{}
((({[{{{([<{{<<><>><[][]>}{({}())<<>{}>}}[{([]())}[<<>()>({}[])]]>{<[<<>[]]<()<>>][[()[]][<>[]]]>[{[[]
<(<<[[<{({{[(([][]))([<><>][{}{}])]}})}>]](<([{{[{<{[][]}[{}<>]>([{}()])}]}([{{(())}{{{}{}}<[]{}
<([<[{{({[(({({}{})<{}()>}))[[((<><>)<{}>)[[[][]]((){})]]<<<[]()>{()[]}>>]]{<<(<[]<>>[<>{}]){({}())}>>}}{[[
[<<[(({<({{{[{[][]}{(){}}][<()()>]}((<{}{}>>[{{}[]}])}{<[(<>[])[(){}]](<<><>>({}<>))><(({}())
[([{<{(([[[([{{}[]}<(){}>])]<{([[]()][[]<>])([{}{}]([][]))}>]({<<([][]){()<>}>>{([()<>]([])){{{}()}{[][]}
{<({[<[(({{({<(){}><[][]>}[{<>()}({})])<[[{}]{<><>}]<<[]{}>([]{})>>}[(({[]<>})([(){}]<()[]>))]}))]><<(
{<<[[<[[[((<[<{}<>><<><>>]<({}[])([]{})>>{<{()<>}>{([]{})[()[]]}}>[[<({}<>)([]{})>(<{}()>[[]()])][[<()<>><[]
{((({(<{[[[({<<>[]><{}<>>}[{[][]}[<>()]]){([<>()][[]()])({[]<>}{{}<>})}]<<{[{}<>]<{}()>}<(()){(){}}>>{
<[[{<<([<[{{(({}()){[]{}}){{{}[]}{<>()}}}}{<{[<><>]<{}{}>}(({}()){()<>})>(<(<>{})[<>()]>{<<><>>{[][]}}
{{([{(((({<{[({}{}){{}{}}]{(<>{})[{}{}]}}[{[()[]][{}()]}{(()[])(()())}]><({(<>[])}((())<[]>))>}<{{{{{}<>
({(([({(<<<((({}[])((){}))((<><>)[[][]]))((<()<>><(){}>){{{}()}(()[])})><([[{}<>][()[]]])(([<>
<<<<<{({{([(([{}{}]<{}()>))][<<{<>[]}{<>}>({()<>}{{}()})>[([<><>]{{}()})([[]{}])}]){({[([]<>)<[][]>][{<><>
((<[<<{{<([{{[{}<>]{{}<>}}([[][]]<<>{}>)}{[[[]{}]])]{[<<{}<>>{{}{}}><({}<>)>]([(<><>)[{}()]])})(<
<(((<[(((<([[{(){}}<<>()>]]<{<<>{}><(){}>}<{[][]}{[]{}}>>)>{<<{{<><>}{[]<>}}{{<>[]}<[]()>}>[{{{}()}{[]<>
{[<{((<<[<<([(()()){{}()}](([]{}){<>()>))>{({((){})({}())}[[()][<><>]])<([{}[]][[]{}])(([]{}){()<>}
(<[({[(([[{[[<{}{}><<>{}>][<<>{}>]]([{<>()}<<>{}>]{{[]{}}({}())})}([({{}()}{{}()})][[<<>[]>[<>{}]]{<<>[])}])
{<{(((<([[[<[(<>())[()[]]]<<()[]><{}<>>>>]<{({<>()}(()<>)){<<><>>{{}[]}}}{(<()<>><<>[]>){{[]()}[[]()]}}>][(<[
<<[[<(({{{{<{{[]()}({}<>)}[(<>{}){[]{}}]>[<{[][]}{{}{}}>]}{{(<<>()><{}{}>)[{{}[])[(){}]]}(([()[]][{}[]]){<
(<(<<<([{((<[[{}[]]{{}}]<({}<>)<()<>>>})<(<[<>{}]<{}<>>><([]<>)([]<>)>)[{<{}<>>[()()]}[(<>[])]
<{(([([[<<([{{<><>}[<><>}}{[{}<>]{{}<>}}]{([[]()]<()[]>)[({}<>){[][]}]})({[((){})<<>[]>][{<>()}[[]<>]
<<<{{<{[({<<[[[]][[][]]]({[]()}{{}[]})>>{[({{}<>}{[][]})[[{}()]{[]}]]}}([[[[<>[]]<{}[]>]{[{}{
{<{{([([<{[[{([]<>)[()<>]}][{<()()>}<{{}<>}([]{})>]]{{[{[][]}<{}[]>]([<>()]{{}{}})}{(({}{})((
<{<((<{<{([<((()<>){()[]}){[[]<>](()[])}><(([]()])<[[]()]{{}<>}>>]{({<()><()()>}[[()<>]<<>[]>]
[<[{[(<<[(<<<(<>[])[[]]>{<(){}>}><([<>[]]{<>{}})[{<><>}{[]()}]>>{[(<[]<>>)<[{}<>]{<>()}>]{<(()())[[][]]>[
[<<<{[(<<[({{{<>[]}<[]()>}{<<>[]>(<>[]]}})]>>{[[<({([][]){{}()}}[{<>()}({}())])({(()[])(<>
[<[[<{<{{{{{<([]())[<>()]><{()<>}[<><>]>}}}}}><<{(([{<[][]>{[]()}}[{[][]}{{}<>}>][(({}())({}())
<[[{{[<{<<[<(<<>[]>)<<()()>{{}[]}>>{<{()<>}[<><>]>[{{}{}}{()}]}]{(<([]<>)({}())>{<[]{}>}){[({}())]{(
({{[(([(<{[[{(()<>)({}())}<({}{}){{}}>](((()())<{}()>)[<{}<>><{}()>])]({{([][])({}<>)}<({}())<[]
{[(<[<{[(([<(<[]()><{}()>)<<[][]><()>>>][<<[{}[]]<{}{}>](<<>>{<>[]})>[{(<>())[<>]}<{[]<>}((
[{{(<{{[{<<<<(<><>)>(({}[]))><<[[]{}][<>()]>>>({[({}{}){<>{}}]<[<><>]>})>}<[<{{<{}{}>{<><>}}}>]<(
{<{<<{[{<[[[<<{}[]>{()<>}>(<()[]>({}<>))]{<((){})[<><>]><{<>{}}{<>()}>}]({([()[]]{[]()})}([{()()}}<(<>()
[<<([(<[<[[([(<>{}){()<>}][<{}()><{}()>])]((([()<>]{()<>})[[<><>]]))][{([{{}{}}]<{<>}[{}()]>)[[{
<[[{([({<<<(<([]<>)<<><>>>[{[]()}<(){}>])>>>({(([[<>{}]([]<>)]{[(){}](()())})([{<>()}([]<>)]))<[{[{}()]{<>[]}
<(([{<{[[<({[({}()){{}[]}]{<{}[]>[{}<>]}}[[[{}<>](<><>)][<()()>({}<>)]])<{{[{}<>]{<>[]}}}([[{}[]]<<>{}>])>>
{(<[([[[{[<[[<[]()>[{}{}]][<()[]>{[]()}]]>[[[(<>[]){<>[]}][{<>{}}<()[]>]]]](<{{([]())[()()]]<[{}[]][[](
[([[[<<<{({[[{[][]}<()[]>]][{{[]()}([]<>)}({()<>})]))[<{<[<>{}]{[]{}}>({<>{}}[()()])}><<([<>[]]{{}[]})[<[][]
{(({({<{([[[[<[]{}>(<>{})]{({}())(()<>)}]]<{{<[]()>(()())}{([][])}}<{[[][]]<()<>>}{(<>{})({}
[{{<[{(<{({<[{[]<>}[[]()]][[{}<>]{{}()}]>(<[()()]>([{}[]]{(){}}))}{{{({}<>)<<><>>}({[]<>)<{}>)}})([<({
(<[{{{{<(<[<{{()()}{[]{}}}<([]{}){<>()}>>[({{}<>}{{}[]})]][[({{}()}(<>[])){<[][]>[<>()]}]]>]>{[(
[{<(<<{[<(<[<({}[])({}{})>]{<{{}()}<<><>>>{<{}{}>(()())}}>)>][({<[[<(){}>(<>())](({}{}){{}()}
{([[{<{<{(([<([]<>)[<>]>{(<>[]){<>[]}}][<[(){}]{{}()}>((<>[]))])<({[()<>](()[])}){<[()<>]{<>{}}>{([])<()
<[{[{(<<({[((<[]{}>{[]{}})([()[]]<(){}>))<{<<>[]>[{}]}{<{}<>>{()}}>]{{{(<>())}(({}<>))}<<{()<>}({}())>([{}<
<(<[{{<{{[([{{(){}}<<>{}>}(<(){}>)][[{{}<>}(()<>)]]){([<<>{}>[()()]][{[]()}<{}()>])}]<{([{[]}([][]
<[[{<{[<{([<[<[]<>][{}]]<({}{})([])>>]({{(<><>)[[]<>]}<<{}[]>[[]<>]>}))}([<(({()()}{[]<>}))<{<()[]><[]()>}(((
({{{<{([{<[{{[{}<>](<><>)}[[<>()]({}[])]}[[<(){}>({}<>)]<(()())({}())>])>[<<<[[][]][(){}]><([
((<{[<[[(((<[<<>()>([]())]<(()<>){()[]}>>[<{(){}}{{}}>[[(){}}<[]{}>]])<[[[[][]][{}()]]{[{}()][
(({[[<{({[[[[[<><>]<[]{}>]<(<>{}){[]()}>][(([]<>){()[]})([<>{}]<()<>>)]]]}[[<{<(<><>)<{}[]>>}<<{<>
<{({[{(([[{(<(()[])<(){}>>{<{}{}>{<><>}})[<(()())<[]{}>>]}[{{{[]}[()[]]}[<()[]><<>{}>]}{<[<><>]{[]
[<[<<{<{{<[(<{(){}}[<>()]><({}<>)<<>{}>))<<<()<>>({}<>)><[<><>][()]>>](({({}()){()()}}<[[]<>]<<>{}>>)<[[[]
{<{(<(<[<([{<{{}[]}(()[])>[({}())<[][]>]}<<{()()}[<><>]>>]<{{[[]{}]{<><>}}(({}{})[[]])}({(<>[])<<>{}>
{{{[[((<[(<<[[{}()]<[]<>>]{<()[]>}>[<<()()>>([<><>]((){}))]>{<<[{}{}][{}()]>[(()())[<>[]]]>{{
<({<{[{<[<({{[<><>]{<>[]}}<{[]<>}<<><>>]}{{[{}{}]{{}{}}}{<[]<>>{[][]}}})(<({()<>}<{}[]>){([]{})
{<(<<[<{([{[({{}<>}[()()]){(()<>)[{}<>]}]}])}>]{{(<[<<((()())<<>()>)>{([[]{}]((){}))<({}<>)({}<
[<(<[[{{[([[<<[]{}>{[]<>}>{(<>[])[{}{}]>]([[[]<>](()())])])([[<{<>{}}(<><>)><({}<>)<()>>][({[]<>}
[<{({{[<([{<{[()[]][(){}]}>[([<>[]]{{}})]}<<((()<>}(()()))<[(){}]>>((({}())[{}<>]){({}<>)<<>[]>})>]{<<{<{}[]
[[<{<{({(<{<{({}())[{}]}([()[]]{{}()})>}((([{}{}]{()<>})<[<>()]{<>[]}>)[([()<>]<<><>>)[[()[]]{[]}]]]>){([[[
{<(([<<[<{(((<()<>>{{}()})({[]{}}[[]{}]))(([{}[]]{[]<>})<<[]>(<>{})>))}[{{<(<><>]<<>>>}}({[({}[])
[[{{[([<[({[{(<>()}[<>[]]}{{<>{}}<[]{}>}]{{{()[]}([]{})}([()<>]{()<>})}}[<{(<>)<<><>>}{{<>[]}<<>[]>}>({<
{{[{{{<([<{<{<{}<>>}{[(){}]{{}()}}><{{[]()}<{}>}>)[[{[{}{}]{()<>}}<(<>{}){[]{}}>][[(()<>)(<>())]({[]<>}[()[]
((<({<{[(<[{[<<>><{}()>][[{}[]>]}{({()<>}[{}[]])[(()())]}][<<{<>{}}<<><>>>[{[][]}{<>()}]>]>[<({({}()){{
[([<<({({[<{(((){}){<>{}})(({}<>))}{<[[]()][{}{}]>{([][])<[][]>}}>]<<(<{<>()}[()[]]>[<(){}>[<>()>])<<[{}(
```

**AOC_10_brackets.py**

```
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Annotated, Generator, Iterable, TypeVar, Union

Score = Annotated[
    Union[int, float],
    "A value representing the score of a line according to some restriction",
]


BRACKET_PARTNERS = {
    "(": ")",
    "{": "}",
    "[": "]",
    "<": ">",
    ")": "(",
    "}": "{",
    "]": "[",
    ">": "<",
}


@dataclass
class Bracket:
    name: str
    is_open: bool
    syntax_error_score: Score = 0
    autocomplete_score: Score = 0

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.is_closed = not self.is_open

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"'{self.name}'"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def partner(self):
        partner = BRACKET_PARTNERS[self.name]
        return BRACKET_TYPES[partner]


BRACKET_TYPES = {
    "(": Bracket("(", True),
    "[": Bracket("[", True),
    "{": Bracket("{", True),
    "<": Bracket("<", True),
    ")": Bracket(")", False, syntax_error_score=3, autocomplete_score=1),
    "]": Bracket("]", False, syntax_error_score=57, autocomplete_score=2),
    "}": Bracket("}", False, syntax_error_score=1197, autocomplete_score=3),
    ">": Bracket(">", False, syntax_error_score=25137, autocomplete_score=4),
}


@dataclass
class Brackets:
    """Takes in a list of brackets and checks if the brackets are incomplete or corrupted

    If a closing bracket appears before the matching opening bracket, the
    line is marked as corrupted.

    If the number of opening brackets is greater than the number of closing
    brackets, and the line is not corrupted the line is marked as
    incomplete

    Example:
        # Legal brackets
        >>> Brackets.from_string('')
        Brackets('')

        >>> Brackets.from_string('()')
        Brackets('()')

        >>> Brackets.from_string('{()()()}')
        Brackets('{()()()}')

        >>> Brackets.from_string('<([{}])>')
        Brackets('<([{}])>')

        >>> Brackets.from_string('[<>({}){}[([])<>]]')
        Brackets('[<>({}){}[([])<>]]')

        >>> Brackets.from_string('(((((((((())))))))))')
        Brackets('(((((((((())))))))))')

        # Corruped brackets
        >>> Brackets.from_string('(]')
        Brackets('(]', corrupted)

        >>> Brackets.from_string('{()()()>')
        Brackets('{()()()>', corrupted)

        >>> Brackets.from_string('(((()))}')
        Brackets('(((()))}', corrupted)

        >>> Brackets.from_string('{([(<{}[<>[]}>{[]{[(<()>')
        Brackets('{([(<{}[<>[]}>{[]{[(<()>', corrupted)

        # Incomplete brackets
        >>> Brackets.from_string('(')
        Brackets('(', incomplete)

        >>> Brackets.from_string('([{<')
        Brackets('([{<', incomplete)

        >>> Brackets.from_string('<{([{{}}[<[[[<>{}]]]>[]]')
        Brackets('<{([{{}}[<[[[<>{}]]]>[]]', incomplete)

        >>> Brackets.from_string('[({(<(())[]>[[{[]{<()<>>')
        Brackets('[({(<(())[]>[[{[]{<()<>>', incomplete)
    """

    brackets: list[Bracket]
    incomplete: bool = False
    corrupted: bool = False
    syntax_error_score: Score = 0
    autocomplete_score: Score = 0

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.incorrect_bracket = None
        self.opened_brackets = []
        self.check_bracket_balance()

        self.autocomplete = self.get_closing_brackets()

        self.calculate_score()

    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            f"Brackets('{''.join(map(str, self.brackets))}'"
            f"{', incomplete' if self.incomplete else ''}"
            f"{', corrupted' if self.corrupted else ''}"
            ")"
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return "".join(map(str, self.brackets))

    def check_bracket_balance(self):
        """Checks if the line number of opening brackets and closing brackets match"""
        for bracket in self.brackets:

            if bracket.is_open:
                self.opened_brackets.append(bracket)
                continue

            if (last_opened_bracket := self.pop_open_bracket()) is not None:
                brackets_match = last_opened_bracket.partner == bracket
            else:
                # This triggers when the number of opened brackets is empty
                # E.g a closing bracket appears before an opening bracket
                brackets_match = False

            if not brackets_match:
                self.incorrect_bracket = bracket
                self.corrupted = True
                return

        # If there are un-closed brackets after reading the entire line mark it as incomplete
        if self.opened_brackets:
            self.incomplete = True

    def pop_open_bracket(self):
        try:
            return self.opened_brackets.pop()
        except IndexError:
            return None

    def get_closing_brackets(self):
        """Returns the neccecary brackets to match every open bracket with a closing bracket

        Example:
            >>> Brackets.from_string(')').get_closing_brackets()
            []
            >>> Brackets.from_string('(').get_closing_brackets()
            [')']
            >>> Brackets.from_string('([{').get_closing_brackets()
            ['}', ']', ')']
            >>> Brackets.from_string('<{([{{}}[<[[[<>{}]]]>[]]').get_closing_brackets()
            [']', ')', '}', '>']
        """
        if not self.opened_brackets:
            return []
        return [bracket.partner for bracket in self.opened_brackets[::-1]]

    def calculate_score(self):
        """Calculates the syntax error score and the autocomplete score of the line"""
        if self.incorrect_bracket is not None:
            self.syntax_error_score = self.incorrect_bracket.syntax_error_score
            return

        # If a line has a syntax error, it it not possible to autocomplete it
        for bracket in self.autocomplete:
            self.autocomplete_score *= 5
            self.autocomplete_score += bracket.autocomplete_score

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, string: str) -> Brackets:
        brackets = []
        for char in string:
            if (bracket := BRACKET_TYPES.get(char, None)) is not None:
                brackets.append(bracket)
        return cls(brackets)


T = TypeVar("T")
V = TypeVar("V")


def with_attributes(
    lines: Iterable[T], attributes: Union[str, list[str]], values: Union[V, list[V]]
) -> Generator[T, None, None]:
    """Yields lines where every attribute matches every value"""
    list_of_attributes = attributes if isinstance(attributes, list) else [attributes]
    list_of_values = values if isinstance(values, list) else [values]

    for line in lines:
        for attribute, value in zip(list_of_attributes, list_of_values):
            if not getattr(line, attribute) == value:
                break
        else:
            yield line


def median(numbers: list[Union[float, int]]) -> Union[float, int]:
    """Calculates the median from a list of numbers

    The indices in the middle are

    (len(nums) - 1) // 2 and len(nums) // 2.

    If the length is odd, then these indices are equal, so adding the
    values and dividing by 2 has no effect.

    Example:
        >>> median([])
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        IndexError: list index out of range
        >>> median([2])
        2
        >>> median([0, 1])
        0.5
        >>> median([0, 100, 1])
        1
    """
    numbers.sort()
    middle1 = ((length := len(numbers)) - 1) // 2
    middle2 = length // 2
    if middle1 == middle2:
        return numbers[middle1]
    return (numbers[middle1] + numbers[middle2]) / 2


def read_brackets_from(path: Path) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if brackets_as_string := line.strip():
                yield brackets_as_string


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest

    doctest.testmod(
        extraglobs={
            "Brackets": Brackets,
        }
    )

    # PATH_2_BRACKETS = Path("AOC_10_brackets_test_01.txt")
    PATH_2_BRACKETS = Path("AOC_10_brackets.txt")
    bracket_strings = read_brackets_from(PATH_2_BRACKETS)
    brackets = [Brackets.from_string(string) for string in bracket_strings]

    # Part 1
    corrupted_brackets = with_attributes(brackets, "corrupted", True)
    print(sum(x.syntax_error_score for x in corrupted_brackets))

    # Part 2
    incomplete_lines = with_attributes(brackets, "incomplete", True)
    autocomplete_scores = [x.autocomplete_score for x in incomplete_lines]
    print(median(autocomplete_scores))
```