# Check for matching symbols

Tags: python

The following code is a working solution for the [balanced parentheses problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/).

I'm really just wondering about coding style here when it comes to separating out related if-statements.

When there are two related if-statements, and where the second is run if the first is run, should I merge all checks into one complete if-statement, as in,

```
if char in open_close_parens and stack and stack[-1] == open_close_parens[char]:
```

or separate out the two if-statements as I've done here, with the  check for an empty stack (list) then being more prominent in the second follow-up if-statement?

```
 def is_valid(stri: str) -> bool:
    stack = []
    open_close_parens = {
        ')':'(', 
        ']':'[', 
        '}':'{'
    }

    for char in stri:
            if char in open_close_parens:
                # if stack is not empty and there is a match, pop it
                if stack and stack[-1] == open_close_parens[char]:
                    stack.pop()
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                stack.append(char) 

    return not stack

print(is_valid(']'))
print(is_valid('()'))
```

Comment: Is "using nested `if` statements in loop" part of the code requirements, or just an artefact of how you solved the problem?  If the latter, I'd recommend removing from the title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would not combine those terms, but there are a few minor improvements.

- Naming: Naming things is hard, but you have some improvements. You should try to use accurate terminology when writing code. You are not checking for parenthesis. You are checking for brackets, where parenthesis `()` is a special case of brackets.

  Similarly `stri` is a bad name. Something like `brackets` is better and because of the typing hint we know it is a string.

  `pen_close_parens` can be named `bracket_pairs` and should be a global constant. So `BRACKET_PAIRS`.
- Early exits and `continue`: A way to clean up the logic is early exits and `continue`.
- Tests are nicely placed inside of docstrings.

### Code:

```
BRACKET_PAIRS = {")": "(", "]": "[", "}": "{"}


def balanced_brackets(brackets: str) -> bool:
    """Returns true if the number of brackets are balanced

    >>> balanced_brackets("]")
    False
    >>> balanced_brackets("()")
    True
    """
    stack = []

    for bracket in brackets:
        if bracket not in BRACKET_PAIRS:
            stack.append(bracket)
            continue

        # if stack is not empty and there is a match, pop it
        if not (stack and stack[-1] == BRACKET_PAIRS[bracket]):
            return False

        stack.pop()

    return not stack


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest

    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: @cheznead If you want to expand upon this you can check out this question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/270980/advent-of-code-2021-day-10-syntax-scoring. You can try the problem before looking at my solution =)

The relevant part is `check_bracket_balance`.

Comment: Learning something every day. In my mother language, brackets are a special case of parenthesis. Didn't know it is other way round in English. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, though to be fair, even the question as written on leetcode uses "parentheses" in one place to refer to all of `[]{}()`.

Comment: @DavidZ *Shrugs* Just because one site uses a certain terminology does not make it right. I'd trust wikipedia more than leetcode when it comes to correct language https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket. 

Now, In English and programming both the terms `parenthesis` and `brackets` are often used when talking about single instances. "You need to add some curly parenthesis here" (Note that just because we use it informally does not make it correct.) However, when we talk about a group of them, it is more correct to use `bracket`. Also `square bracket` is shortened to just `bracket` singularly.

Comment: I would use DeMorgan on that second condition: `if not stack or stack[-1] != BRACKET_PAIRS[bracket]:`, maybe that's just a personal preference...

Comment: @Jasmijn agree. The reason why I left it is that I really wanted to rewrite it as `stack[-1] == BRACKET_PAIRS[bracket]` is cryptc. Better would have been to have defined `brackets_match = stack[-1] == BRACKET_PAIRS[bracket]` and then done `if not brackets_match`. But I would then probably also rename `stack` to `open_brackets` (as in my linked codereview), but there are only so much time in a day to be pedantic...

Answer (score 4):

Remember doing this a while back.
In my opinion, it is all good. It will work for this problem.
The code is nice and easy to read. For small applications, I prefer code as you did with separated if statements, as it is easier to read and understand. Others may not agree, think that it's going to be down to personal preference. Really good points: type hints ;)

Don't know if you noticed but indentation is a bit off in your code, but that probably happened while pasting the code.